# Is there a way to stop Facebook videos from automatically playing without changing my entire browser settings?

Tags: facebook

I've heard about Facebook introducing autoplay videos last year, but I’am only now starting to see them in my news feed. While they initially play without sound unless you click the volume icon, it's still a major annoyance to see things moving around in my news feed. I'd like to put a stop to this if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Go to `https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=videos`.

The page should say **Video settings**, and an option on the right to disable auto-playing. I just tried it and videos do not start automatically anymore while scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn Facebook's video auto-play settings on or off. To stop videos from playing automatically on your computer:

1. From the top right of Facebook, click [image] and select **Settings**
2. Click [Videos](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=videos) in the left menu
3. Click the dropdown menu next to **Auto-play Videos** and select **Off**

[Source](https://www.facebook.com/help/1406493312950827).

On mobile:

You can adjust the Facebook app's auto-play settings to **On**, **Wi-Fi only** or **Off**.

To adjust the auto-play settings on your Android phone or tablet:

1. Open the Facebook app
2. Tap [image]
3. Scroll down and tap **App Settings**
4. Tap **Video Auto-play**
5. Choose an option

Note: If you don't see the **Video Auto-play** settings on your Android phone, log out of the Facebook app. When you log back into Facebook, **Video Auto-play** should be visible in **App Settings**.

To adjust the auto-play settings on your iPhone or iPad:

1. Open the Facebook app
2. Tap [image]
3. Scroll down and tap **Settings**
4. Tap **Videos** > **Autoplay**
5. Choose an option

Note: If you don't see **Videos** in your iPhone or iPad's Facebook app settings, try updating the Facebook app.

[Source](https://www.facebook.com/help/mobile-touch/1406493312950827).

Answer (score 0):

Update: this answer is obsolete.

---

Facebook unfortunately has no option to disable autoplay. The best you can do is using a browser extension such as [F.B. Purity Cleans Up Facebook](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fb-purity-cleans-up-faceb/ncdlagniojmheiklojdcpdaeepochckl/details?hl=en) for Google Chrome.

Comment: This is now possible.